# Difference Between .Net FrameWork and .Net Mono FrameWork

Tags: .net, frameworks, mono

I want to know what is the difference between .Net Framework and .Net MonoframeWork

Comment: may be this link will be useful http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net Framework contain set of libraries to develop software using various programming languages like c#,vb.net,F# etc.
The Mono .Net Framework is an opensource framework of .Net whose application can be deployed
on Other Operating system like Linux,Mac OS

Comment: You can run mono on windows too, and Solaris and Android and iPhoneOS

Answer (score 4):

The Mono framework is opensource implementation of Microsoft .net framework

Comment: I'd say that it is open source implementation of appropriate ECMA standards with additional implementation of some technologies not covered by these standards.

Answer (score 0):

Mono framework has the limited component the compact version we can say mono framework but .Net framework is the wide in this we use various programming languages like c#, vb.net, F# etc.